# Adobe PDF embedded JavaScript executing outside function

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have searched in vain to find the answer.  I have a PDF that I want to embed some JS in but need to know if I can invoke a function that is not contained within the PDF, the function is part of the web page that the PDF is shown in an iframe.  Does anyone know?

Comment: Execution of JavaScript inside a PDF is always done by the PDF reader in question, and for web pages, it depends on the browser and/or the plug-ins loaded in the browser. So each PDF reader might do things differently. That said, I can't imagine any PDF viewer would support it. The goal of PDF is to be self-contained as much as possible and platform-independent as much as possible. This is very much platform / implementation dependent.